# How to get subtree of an Xpath expression?

Tags: java, dom, xpath

If say I’ve got the following XML file:

```
<title text=“title1">
    <comment id=“comment1">
        <data> this is part of comment one</data>
        <data> this is some more of comment one</data>
    </comment>
    <comment id=“comment2”>
        <data> this is part of comment two</data>
        <data> this is some more of comment two</data>
        <data> this is even some more of comment two</data>
    </comment>
</title>
```

And I’m given the following XPath query:

```
/title/comment/@id
```

What would be the best way to get the subtree to which the expression belongs.

So for instance, the above expression would return:

- `id="comment1"`
- `id="comment2"`

To which, `comment1` belongs to subtree:

```
    <comment id="comment1">
        <data> this is part of comment one</data>
        <data> this is some more of comment one</data>
    </comment>
```

And, `comment2` belongs to subtree:

```
    <comment id=“comment2">
        <data> this is part of comment two</data>
        <data> this is some more of comment two</data>
        <data> this is even some more of comment two</data>
    </comment>
```

The reason I want this is so that I can recursively make a call on the sub-tree where the Xpath expression is resolved to.

I am coding this in Java using DOM.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question properly: do you need to get the comment elements? comment elements having an id attribute?

Comment: What I want to do is: given some xpath expression (e.g. `/title/comment/@id`), I want a way to formulate or obtain the sub-tree to which this element or attribute is found in? I.e. `id=comment1` is part of the first `<comment> ... </comment>` subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the XPath expression is unknown until run time.
And you want to obtain the parent of each node selected by the XPath expression... is that right? The `<comment>` element is the parent of each `comment/@id` attribute. Obtaining the `<comment>` element is equivalent to obtaining its subtree (descendants), because you can extract its descendants using further XPath expressions or DOM functions, or you can copy the `<comment>` element *with* its descendants.

One way to answer your question then is to simply append "/.." to the end of the XPath expression. E.g.

```
"/title/comment/@id"
```

would become

```
"/title/comment/@id/.."
```

which is equivalent to @Dan's answer, but can be easily derived from whatever the XPath expression may be.

Comment: Perfect! this is just what I needed. So what’s the best way to copy say some `<comment>` Node together with its children into a new DOM Document?

Comment: @Larry: I would look at using importNode() and appendChild() (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/JavaDOMeditCopyaNodefromOneParseTreeintoAnother.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
/title/comment[@id]
```

Would retrieve all comment elements with an id attribute.

Comment: What about if say my xpath expression is `/title/comment/data/text()` the subtree I want here are: `<data> this is part of comment one</data>`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression returns nodes, in your case attribute nodes. The calling Java code can do whatever it likes with these nodes, for example navigate to their parent or to the descendants of their parents.

But instead of doing half the work in XPath and half in Java, why not do it all in XSLT or XQuery?